# A matrix problem about egienvalue and trace

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations, matrix-calculus, hessian-matrix

Consider an  $m\times m$ positive definite and Hermitian matrix $\mathbf{M}$
and an arbitrary $m\times n (m>n)$  para-unitary matrix  $\mathbf{R}$, i.e.,
$\mathbf{R}^H\mathbf{R}=\mathbf{I}_n$.

then， is there any strict proof for:
Let $\mu_1,...,\mu_{n}$ and
$\lambda_1,...,\lambda_{n}$ denote the eigenvalues in descending order of
$(\mathbf{R}^H\mathbf{M}\mathbf{R})^{-1}$ and
$\mathbf{R}^H\mathbf{M}^{-1}\mathbf{R}$, respectively,  we have
$\mu_k \le \lambda_k, \forall k$. ?

I use matlab and generate many random matrices to check the result. I think it must be true. However, how to prove it?

Comment: You don't get equality?  If $R$ is para-unitary, so is $R^{-1}$, where you would get the reverse inequality (I think?).

Comment: actually R is not a square matrix, so I think $R^{-1}$ does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

By a change of orthonormal basis, we may assume that $R^H=\pmatrix{I_n&0}$. Let us write
$$
M=\pmatrix{A&B^H\\ B&C}, \text{ so that } M^{-1}=\pmatrix{(A-B^HC^{-1}B)^{-1}&\ast\\ \ast&\ast}
$$
where $A-B^HC^{-1}B$ is the [Schur complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur_complement) of $C$ in $M$. Then
$$
(R^HMR)^{-1}=A^{-1}\prec(A-B^HC^{-1}B)^{-1}=R^HM^{-1}R
$$
and the result follows.